# specializing member S::display requires ‘template<>’ syntax

Tags: c++

I'm creating a trait class to help with my program. I have a template class called `operations` that contains the methods `display` and `area`. When I define these functions I get errors. Here they are:

> error: specializing member `‘traits::operations<Rectangle>::display’` requires `‘template<>’` syntax
>   error: specializing member `‘traits::operations<Rectangle>::area’` requires `‘template<>’` syntax

As you can see, the compiler wants me to insert `template <>` just before those definitions. But when I do, I get a huge page of errors. What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Here is my program.

```
namespace traits
{
    template <typename P>
    struct operations
    {
        static void display(Rectangle const &, std::ostream &);
        static void area(Rectangle const &);
    };

    template <typename P, int N>
    struct access {};
}

namespace traits
{
    template <int N>
    struct access<Rectangle, N>
    {
        static double get(Rectangle const &);
    };
}

// The errors occur here
namespace traits
{
    static void operations<Rectangle>::display(Rectangle const &rect, std::ostream &os)
    {
        os << rect.width  << '\n';
        os << rect.height << '\n';
        os << area(rect)  << '\n'; 
    }

    static void operations<Rectangle>::area(Rectangle const& rect)
    {
        double width =  get<0>(rect);
        double height = get<1>(rect);

        return width * height;
    }
}

namespace traits
{
    template <>
    struct access<Rectangle, 0>
    {
        static double get(Rectangle const &rect)
        {
            return rect.width;
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct access<Rectangle, 1>
    {
        static double get(Rectangle const &rect)
        {
            return rect.height;
        }
    };
}

template <int N, typename P>
static inline double get(P const &p)
{
    return traits::access<P, N>::get(p);
}

template <typename P>
static inline void display(P const &p)
{
    traits::operations<P>::display(p, std::cout);
}

template <typename P>
static inline double area(P const &p)
{
    return traits::operations<P>::area(p);
}

int main()
{

}
```

Here is a program which shows the error - http://ideone.com/WFlnb2#view_edit_box

Any and all help is appreciated.

---

Thanks to help from the comments I got rid of those two errors, but I'm not getting more after adding the `template<>` declaration and fixing the return type of `area`:

> error: cannot declare member function `‘static void traits::operations<P>::display(const Rectangle&, std::ostream&) [with P = Rectangle; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’` to have static linkage [-fpermissive]
>   error: explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class
>   error: specialization of `‘static double traits::operations<P>::area(const Rectangle&) [with P = Rectangle]’` after instantiation
>   error: explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class

Comment: For starters, your `void area(Rectangle const &);` member should probably be returning a `double`, especially since you expect it to later on.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, but still get the same errors.

Comment: The error is correct; You're specializing `operations` to `Rectangle`, and as such you must provide an empty `template<>` header before the specialization definition. Fixing that and the return type of `area()` leaves only trying to understand wth you're doing with the `access::get` member. Still don't understand what your intent is there.

Comment: @WhozCraig `get` works fine. I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: I'll take your word on that, because on my rig fixing the return type of `area()` and providing the empty template parameter list for the specialization leaves only `get()` failing to compile, and as near as I can tell it may be because of the order this was pasted into the question. In the order provided above it won't compile for me unless `get()` is specifically  resolved, i.e. `access<Rectangle, 0>::get(rect)`. But if you don't think thats an issue, s'ok. whatever works for you. **EDIT** I probably should have mentioned. I also lost the `static`, as a static specialization doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your functions : `display` and `area` should be write like this:

```
    template <>
    double operations<Rectangle>::area( Rectangle const& rect )
    {
            double width =  get<0>(rect);
            double height = get<1>(rect);

            return width * height;
    }
```

- As for template specialized functions, `template <>` should be placed
  at the head of the function.
- For static member functions, `static` should not appear at the
  definition body of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
template< typename P > // P is declared here
struct operations  {
    ... // into this scope
}; // but it goes out of scope here

template< typename P > // So it needs to be redeclared
void operations::display( Rectangle const &, std::ostream &) {
    ... // for this scope.
}
```

The function `display` doesn't "own" the names of its parameters. The template parameter must be redeclared in the definition. The compiler message is referring to `template<>` syntax to suggest you place something inside the `<>` brackets, but confusingly, leaving the brackets empty and literally saying `template<>` means something else — explicit specialization, which isn't what you want here.

On the other hand, `static` is a property of a member function which does *not* get mentioned in the definition. The compiler remembers `static` after using the other parts of the definition signature to match it to the declaration signature. So, you should erase `static` from the definition.