# resolving a specializing member requires 'template<>' syntax

Tags: c++

I currently have something like this that works fine in Visual Studio however I get the following error in Mingw

```
error: specializing member '{anonymous}::Buffer<{anonymous}::VertexBufferFactory, IDirect3DVertexBuffer9*, ktVertexBuffer>::applyBuffer' requires 'template<>' syntax
 void VertexBuffer::applyBuffer(uint32_t no, uint32_t stride, uint32_t offset)
      ^
```

The code is

```
typedef Buffer<VertexBufferFactory, ddVertexBuffer,VertexBuffer> VertexBuffer;

void VertexBuffer::applyBuffer(uint32_t no, uint32_t stride, uint32_t offset)
{
    Gpu::ddSetStreamSource(no, buffer, offset, stride);
}
```

The template declaration of buffer is

```
template <class FACTORY, class BUFFER, class BASE>
class Buffer : public BASE {
}
```

Any suggestions on why I am getting this error and how to resolve it ?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could provide a complete example, including at least the template declaration for `Buffer`.  Try to reduce the code down to the absolute minimum that is required to reproduce the error, though.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: possible duplicate of [specializing member S::display requires ‘template<>’ syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493187/specializing-member-sdisplay-requires-template-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're defining a member (`applyBuffer`) of a (fully) specialised class template (`Buffer`). The syntax for that uses `template<>` as in

```
template<>
void Buffer<VertexBufferFactory, ddVertexBuffer,VertexBuffer>
::applyBuffer(uint32_t no, uint32_t stride, uint32_t offset)
{
    Gpu::ddSetStreamSource(no, buffer, offset, stride);
}
```